# How get data out of current context with dust.js

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I'm working with Dust.js and trying to use the dust.makeBase function to merge and render data from two arrays (*datax* and *datay*) in an *newcontext* variable.

```
var context = dust.makeBase();
var newcontext = context.push(datax)
                      .push(datay);
```

As Dust documentation the last array pushed (in my sample the *datay*) become the current context. Launching on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4wfj6tz/17/) i can see that data got from current context are displayed correctly.

**Selfstorage Information**

```
   {#.}
   {#data}{id} - {special_offer}
   {/data}
   {/.}
```

However when i came display data out of current context apparently the data is not reached. The following not work.

**Selfstorage Facilities**

```
{#.}
  {#facility}
     {id} - {size}
     {#facilityamenities.amenities}{amenities_id} - {full_desc}    
     {/facilityamenities.amenities}
  {/facility}
{/.}
```

I have got some instructions on http://www.dustjs.com/guides/contexts/ but it isn't enough.

Checking some examples on web i was trought context helpers and i came out with this version on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4wfj6tz/20/) and although a function code is executed the result isn't as expected. Below a piece of code.

```
var context = dust.makeBase({"getselfdata": {
"selfdata": function(chunk, context) 
{
    var price = context.get("facility.price_formatted");

    return price;
}
}});
```

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Your question was excellently-structured and well-written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exactly correct that the last item pushed onto the context becomes the current context. If you push multiple items onto the context, there is no way to reference them by position, for example "the item pushed onto the context before this one".

If you provide Dust a reference that doesn't exist in the current context, Dust will search each previous context for the reference. This allows you to walk up the context stack.

I have made two changes to your example to get it to work. For `datax`, I wrapped the array in an object with one key, `facilities`:

```
{ "facilities": [
    { "facility": { ... } },
    { "facility": { ... } }
]}
```

Then, in your template, I told Dust to search for this reference:

```
{#facilities}
  {#facility}
    <tr><td>{id} - {size} - {#facilityamenities}{#amenities}
      {amenities_id} - {full_desc}
    {/amenities}{/facilityamenities}</td></tr>
  {/facility}
{/facilities}
```

You had one additional bug in this template. For `{#facilityamenities.amenities}` to work, your data would need to look like this:

```
{ "facilityamenities": {
    "amenities": { ... } }
```

However, your `"facilityamenities"` is an array, so instead you should use `{#facilityamenities}{#amenities}` so that Dust will first loop over `facilityamenities`, and then search for `amenities`.

With these changes your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4wfj6tz/21/) works as I believe you intend.